# ERROR LNK2001 AND LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, oculus

i just running program to show sensor data from oculus rift and i have an errors like this:

what should i do to fix the errors????

> Error 13  error LNK1120: 11 unresolved
>   externals E:\TA\Baru\FIX\oculus+ovr\ovrvisionsdk_windows_19022014\ovrvisionsdk_windows\example_vs2008\program\x86\example_wizapply.exe    example_wizapply
>
> Error 10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static
>   float const OVR::Math::PiOver2"
>   (?PiOver2@?$Math@M@OVR@@2MB)  E:\TA\Baru\FIX\oculus+ovr\ovrvisionsdk_windows_19022014\ovrvisionsdk_windows\example_vs2008\main.obj    example_wizapply
>
> Error 10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static
>   float const OVR::Math::PiOver2"
>   (?PiOver2@?$Math@M@OVR@@2MB)  E:\TA\Baru\FIX\oculus+ovr\ovrvisionsdk_windows_19022014\ovrvisionsdk_windows\example_vs2008\main.obj    example_wizapply

Comment: LNK errors is that because visual studio cannot find the specified `.lib` file for the project. Is any library added to project?

Comment: Please read this before you post any more to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Please post Errors as text, not as Image.

Comment: sorry, i already edited my errors. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the project properties->linker->input->additional dependencies and add .lib.

Comment: what .lib name????